# ASP.NET MVC web solution built from optional modules

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I recently came across an awesome NuGet package, called [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/), which enables using background processes in an ASP.NET MVC project. What is interesting about the package though, is that it automatically sets up a nice dashboard subpage (accessible through http://your.url/hangfire) and creates new tables in your database.

I wonder, is it possible to create a whole web solution from optional packages, like Hangfire? Like I would create just a simple home page and all other subpages would be optionally installed via a config file, or in the somewhere in the App_Start? I believe it should be very easy with the new .NET Core 5 and the Startup.cs class (since also SignalR has a Startup.cs class and is then available via http://your.url/signalr/hubs). However, I was unable to find any proper tutorial. Could somebody point me in the right direction?